# How does PCB traces length effects parasitic capacitance on the board

Tags: pcb-design

How does length of trace effects parasitic properties of the PCB board?  Is it longer the length, higher the parasitic?

Answer (score 2):

Capacitance between two plates is proportional to the area of those plates.  Therefore a longer PCB trace above a ground plane, for example, will have more capacitance to ground than a shorter one, assuming everything else is held constant.

Other factors that effect the capacitance is the separation distance and the dielectric constant of the material between the plates.

Answer (score 1):

Posting this just to picturize Mr. Lathrop's answer:

Imagine how a capacitor is formed:

[image]

As you can remember, the capacitance of this capacitor is \$C = \epsilon A/d\$ where \$\epsilon\$ is dielectric constant of material, \$A\$ is surface area of the plates and \$d\$ is the distance between plates. In your example, \$d\$ is the thickness of the PCB and \$A\$ is the surface are of the trace (or plane).

Assuming one side is completely poured-copper for GND, so the parasitic capacitance is proportional to the trace length. The longer the trace, the more the surface area (A) so the more the capacitance.

Answer (score 0):

Even long *thin* traces can have high capacitance, if GND is brought very close to the signal trace. This closeness tends to intercept Efield aggressors, improving SNR, but does load the signal trace and require more charge to sustain the same AC voltage swing.